# iOS 8 boundingRectWithSize Calculates Wrong Text Size

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uitextview

I have a string thats length will change. I have a textView with a fixed width and height. I want to find the maximum font size that will fit within these bounds. I use `boundingRectWithSize`. I assume once it gives me a value larger then my testRect I can lower the font and I should be good. But the string is too large for my textView. I always have to lower it by 2-4 points even though the `testRect.size.height` is lower then my `textView.frame.size.height`.

```c
NSString *testString = @"This is a test string. Does it get biger?";

CGFloat height = self.textView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat width = self.textView.frame.size.width;
CGSize testSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

CGFloat fontSize = 15;

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary;
CGRect testRect;

int i = 0;
while (i == 0) {
    attrsDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]};

    testRect = [testString boundingRectWithSize:testSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attrsDictionary context:nil];

    if (testRect.size.height < testSize.height) {
        fontSize++;
    } else {
        fontSize--;
        self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
        self.textView.text = testString;
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a flawless font your approach should work.
Unfortunately flawless fonts are rare, even system fonts usually aren't.
This means you have to find the required adjustments for your font yourself ...

Comment: What do you mean by flawless font? Is there a way to tell if the text view will scroll to display all text, like a bool value? I cant think of any other logic to do this.

Comment: A flawless font would have all measurement set correct. From my own experience and what I learned in a session by famous font designer, most fonts are far from perfect regarding this: Undercut (gjq..) is a common issue. Even in system fonts a g in the lowest line might be cut of.  There is no global solution afaik, you have to find out the required adjustments per font.